Android share sheet does not display video preview
My app captures a video and saves it to disk using MediaStore. Then, it shares the video using the Android's default share sheet. The code is as following:
private fun shareMediaItem(uri: Uri) {
    try {
        val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Share screen recording")
            type = "video/mp4"
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.clipData = ClipData(null, arrayOf("video/mp4"), ClipData.Item(uri))
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("ShareMediaActivity", "Error sharing media item", e)
    }
}

I expect the share sheet to show the title and a preview of the video, but it only displays an app icon. If I try to share the video using Google Photo though, it displays a preview. Is there a way to make it display the video preview?


I think the answer is no. I didn't find a way to show the video preview.
What you see in Google Photo share ui is just an activity with custom layout, they make it looks like the system's share sheet.
